# How to repeat firing api call out in a while loop till there are no results left in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, node.js-fs

I have an API running in Azure function which needs to be run multiple times in a loop so that i can get all the results .

The first API when it runs. It returns results with **locator** parameter in the heaader. Using the **locator** parmater we need to hit the api inside a loop to get all the results. **locator** paramter will always have a new value when the api is hit.

ANd each time i want to write the response into a new file. How to call the same api with different **locator** parameter till the locator value becomes null

```js
const getjobresult = async(t) => {

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      "Accept": "text/csv",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + t
    },
    redirect: "follow"
  };

  // This below api is called for first time where it returns 500000 records (which i am writing in a file ) and a parameter locator which contains a value through which we will get another set of record
  const resp = await fetch("https://someapi.test.com/services/data/v59.0/jobs/query/750Pw000005PqqBIAS/results?maxRecords=500000", requestOptions)
  const json = await resp.text();
  const fields = ['Id']
  let aa = resp.headers.get('locator')
  const rows = json.split((/\r?\n|\r/)).slice(1);
  let lsttis = []
  rows.forEach(res => {
    let tis = {
      'tablename': 'TestTable'
    };
    tis.AccessLevel = 'Read';
    tis.ParentId = res.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
    tis.RowCause = 'Manual'
    tis.UserOrGroupId = '11111111'
    lsttis.push(tis)
  })

  if (lsttis.length > 0) {
    await creatcsvfile(lsttis)
  }
  // In this below code i am trying to refire the api using locator parameter inside a while loop.Everytime when api gets hit inside while loop, it returns a new locator value. This while loop should run till resp1.headers.get('locator') becomes null and everytime the response should be written in 
  // new file.
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    i++;
    const resp1 = await fetch("https://someapi.com/services/data/v59.0/jobs/query/750Pw000005PqqBIAS/results?locator=" + aa + "&maxRecords=500000", requestOptions)
    const json1 = await resp1.text();
    if (resp1.headers.get('locator') === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    const rows1 = json1.split((/\r?\n|\r/)).slice(1);
    rows1.forEach(res => {
      let tis = {
        'tablename': 'TestTable'
      };
      tis.AccessLevel = 'Read';
      tis.ParentId = res.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
      tis.RowCause = 'Manual'
      tis.UserOrGroupId = '11111111'
      lsttis.push(tis)
    })
    // in this i am sending the i for creating new file for every response.
    if (lsttis.length > 0) {
      await creatcsvfile(lsttis, i)
    }
  }
}

const creatcsvfile = async(data, t) => {
  const fields = ['AccessLevel', 'ParentId', 'RowCause', 'UserOrGroupId']
  let csv = await json2csv.parse(data, {
    fields
  });
  //console.log(csv)
  fs.writeFileSync('./test' + t + '.csv', csv)
}
```

Comment: I don't see you assigning the _new_ locator value to `aa` anywhere.

Comment: yes.. i am struggling how to add it correctly .. i have already added it for first time .  let aa = resp.headers.get('locator')

Comment: And what is the problem now, with doing essentially the same thing again, after your request inside the loop finished? `aa = resp1.headers.get('locator')`

Comment: problem is i want to write it in a more optimized way.

Comment: Then put the first request into the loop as well. No real good reason to make that _before_ the loop here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming that you code works and you are only talking about optimisations I can suggest some tips:

First thing that comes to my mind: don't use var in JavaScript. Hoisting issues can be a problem (not your case), but I really recommend to avoid it.

Second: create functions to segregate duties, create a function like *creatcsvfile* that you made. Crate one just to fetch/parse and another one just to execute the for loop inside the rows. This will create a cleaner and readable code.

Third: you can erase the first api call and all the lines outside your while loop and just adjust things inside it (so you can call all of these just only time), for example:

```
let aa = 0
```

So when you hit the API it will send the locator but it will know that its a first call. If your api doesn't support this, you can crate "aa" as undefined and pass to fetch only when its initialised. Use JS template strings like this:

```
let aa;
const resp1 = await fetch(`https://someapi.com/services/data/v59.0/jobs/query/750Pw000005PqqBIAS/results?${aa? "locator="+aa:""}&maxRecords=500000`, requestOptions)
```

Basically this works as the same, but it doesn't repeat the first declaration and eliminates 20 unnecessary lines.